# Secret creation with SecretProviderClass not working as aspected

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-secrets

EDIT:
It was a config error, I was setting wrong kv name :/

As said in title I'm facing an issue with secret creation using SecretProviderClass.

I've created my aks and my kv (and filled it) on azure. then I'll proceed to follow [those](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver) steps using a user-assigned managed identity

but no `secret` resource get created and pods got stuck on creation with mount failure.

those are the steps I followed

```
az extension add --name aks-preview
az extension update --name aks-preview
az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AKS_CLUSTER 
az aks update -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AKS_CLUSTER --enable-managed-identity --disable-secret-rotation
$AKS_ID = (az aks show -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AKS_CLUSTER --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.clientId -o tsv)
az keyvault set-policy -n $AZUREKEYVAULT --secret-permissions get --spn $AKS_ID
```

the SecretProviderClass manifest I'm using

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: akvsecrets
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - objectName: AzureSignalRConnectionString 
      key: AzureSignalRConnectionString
    - objectName: BlobStorageConnectionString 
      key: BlobStorageConnectionString
    - objectName: SqlRegistryConnectionString 
      key: SqlRegistryConnectionString
    - objectName: TokenSymmetricKey 
      key: TokenSymmetricKey
  parameters:
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID: XXX # VMSS UserAssignedIdentity
    keyvaultName: "sampleaks001" # the name of the KeyVault
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: AzureSignalRConnectionString
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: BlobStorageConnectionString
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: SqlRegistryConnectionString
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: TokenSymmetricKey
          objectType: secret
    resourceGroup: sample # [REQUIRED for version < 0.0.4] the resource group of the KeyVault
    subscriptionId: XXXX # [REQUIRED for version < 0.0.4] the subscription ID of the KeyVault
    tenantId: XXX # the tenant ID of the KeyVault
```

and the deploy manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: trm-api-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: trm-api-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: trm-api-test
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: trm-api-test
        image: nginx
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: AzureSignalRConnectionString
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: akvsecrets
              key: AzureSignalRConnectionString
        - name: TokenSymmetricKey
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: akvsecrets
              key: TokenSymmetricKey
        - name: BlobStorageConnectionString
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: akvsecrets
              key: BlobStorageConnectionString
        - name: SqlRegistryConnectionString
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: akvsecrets
              key: SqlRegistryConnectionString
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "azure-kvname"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: trm-api-service-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: trm-api-test
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't understand what.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the clientId, but it should be the objectId form the kubelet identity:

```
export KUBE_ID=$(az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv)
export AKV_ID=$(az keyvault show -g <resource group> -n <akv name> --query id -o tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $KUBE_ID --role "Key Vault Secrets Officer" --scope $AKV_ID
```

This is a working SecretProviderClass i am using (adjusted to your config):

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - data:
    - objectName: AzureSignalRConnectionString 
      key: AzureSignalRConnectionString
    - objectName: BlobStorageConnectionString 
      key: BlobStorageConnectionString
    - objectName: SqlRegistryConnectionString 
      key: SqlRegistryConnectionString
    - objectName: TokenSymmetricKey 
      key: TokenSymmetricKey
    secretName: akvsecrets
    type: Opaque
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID: XXX # Kubelet Client Id ( Nodepool Managed Idendity )
    keyvaultName: "sampleaks001" # the name of the KeyVault
    tenantId: XXX # the tenant ID of the KeyVault  
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: AzureSignalRConnectionString
          objectAlias: AzureSignalRConnectionString
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: BlobStorageConnectionString
          objectAlias: BlobStorageConnectionString
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: SqlRegistryConnectionString
          objectAlias: SqlRegistryConnectionString
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: TokenSymmetricKey
          objectAlias: TokenSymmetricKey
          objectType: secret
```

You can also check documentation [here](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/sync-with-k8s-secrets/) as you will find better examples as on the Azure Docs.

Comment: On kv i'm not using RBAC, I tried to add object id as set-policy but got same result

Comment: what are you using as userAssignedIdentityID ?

Comment: it must be the same as = az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv

Comment: I used: `az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query addonProfiles.azureKeyvaultSecretsProvider.identity.clientId -o tsv` to get the value for `userAssignedIdentityID`